# My WiiU should have 22GB of free space, but it has only 9GB instead

Tags: technical-issues, wii-u

I can't install Assassin's Creed 3 on the WiiU, because it takes up to 14,2GB of data storage, and I have only 9019MB. I try to understand why, because I should have up to 22GB free.

So, this is all my data:

- Dr Kawashima's Brain Training: 140MB
- Pullblox World: 553MB
- NES REMIX 2: 100MB
- NES REMIX: 388MB
- The Wind Waker HD: 1773MB
- Earthbound: 25MB
- Youtube: 44MB
- DKC: Tropical Freeze (just savegames and updates): 30MB
- ZombiU (just savegames and updates): 34MB
- Mario Kart 8 (just savegames and updates): 149MB
- Super Mario 3D World (just savegames and updates): 39MB

Total: 3265MB

It is known that the WiiU [takes 4.2GB to store the OS](http://bgr.com/2012/11/14/nintendo-wii-u-storage-explained/). So, adding that:

Total: 7555MB

I have a 32GB wiiU. After formatting and other stuff, [there's only 29GB free](http://bgr.com/2012/11/14/nintendo-wii-u-storage-explained/). so if my calculations are not wrong, I should have:

29569 - 7555 = 22141MB

However, the Data management application only shows 9019MB. And the free space bar suggests by the length of the used space that I have 32GB, just in case.

[image: The WiiU Data Management Application]

SO, what's wrong?

Comment: I mean I have absolutly no idea about the wii (i never had one)... But could it be that you have any videos, screenshots, maybe characters (not sure if that exists) that need some space?

Comment: No videos or any other data is being downloaded if not stated on the data management app, I think. I found [this help page](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Wii-U/Storage/How-much-internal-storage-space-is-available-for-saving-data-/How-much-internal-storage-space-is-available-for-saving-data--678131.html) explaining the same I found on another sources. Also, I haven't downloaded any video, music or additional content. Only used the web browser a couple of times. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an error about not enough space when I tried to install the game after buying it.

So I assumed there was not enough space. However, the game is being downloaded, because it's being shown in the download manager.

The game still doesn't appear in the Data Management application. And it is not very obvious that there is an active download without opening the download manager.

Now everything makes sense, 13GB+3GB+9GB=25GB of total space for game storage.